# Entity Mapping in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I would like to convert the following EF 6 code into EF Core 6.

```
HasMany(company => company.AssociatedTo)
                .WithMany(x => x.AssociatedFrom)
                .Map(mc =>
                {
                    mc.MapLeftKey("Company_1");
                    mc.MapRightKey("Company_2");
                    mc.ToTable("Companies_Companies");
                });
```

I have tried this, but for some reason, it doesn't pick any values

```
builder.Entity<Compnay>
        .HasMany(company => company.AssociatedTo)
                .WithMany(x => x.AssociatedFrom)
                .UsingEntity<Companies_Companies>(
                    j => j
                        .HasOne<Company>()
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.Company_1),

                    j => j
                        .HasOne<Company>()
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey(x => x.Company_2)
                );
```

These are my Entity Models:

```
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        ...

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<Company> AssociatedCompanies => (AssociatedFrom ?? new List<Company>())
            .Union(AssociatedTo ?? new List<Company>()).Where(x => x.Id != Id).Distinct().ToArray();

        public virtual ICollection<Company> AssociatedFrom { get; set; } = new List<Company>();

        public virtual ICollection<Company> AssociatedTo { get; set; } = new List<Company>();
...
}
```

And the Companies_Companies Model, I added to support Many-to-Many relationship

```
public class Companies_Companies
    {
        public int Company_1 { get; set; }
        public int Company_2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: And what have you tried already? Did you see this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: Thanks, @Luke, I've updated my question

Yes, I've read it and tried my best.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can we also see how you're querying the data (i.e. do you have your include)? And as Berk KARASU mentioned, it'd be helpful to see your model classes (`Company` and `Companies_Companies`) to make sure your configuration is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I've added my Entity Types to the end of my question.

Comment: @Luke Thanks again, you pointed me in the right direction.  I had to use .Include() in the query to load data for navigation properties.

It seems like with Lazy Loading enabled on DbContext, queries with .AsNoTracking() does not load the related entities :(

Comment: Cool! Yep, you need to have change tracking enabled for lazy loading to work, so that makes sense. If you must use AsNoTracking() then eager loading with the Include is the way to go! Keep in mind that this could still carry some side effects (see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13173 and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10042). Additionally, I always encourage people to reevaluate their decision to lazy load, in favor of eager loading - it can be a serious performance nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

You can establish many to many relationships like this, my score is not enough to comment, but if you share your entityModel, I can help more.

```
 builder.Entity<Compnay>()
          .HasMany(x => x.AssociatedFrom).WithMany(x => x.AssociatedTo)
          .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>("TableNameHere",
          x => x.HasOne<Compnay>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("CompnayId").HasConstraintName("CompnayFK"),
          x => x.HasOne<AssociatedFromModels>().WithMany().HasForeignKey("AssociatedFromId").HasConstraintName("AssociatedFromFK"));
```